# Cherrypy / Python: How to run block access to specific pages by port

Tags: python, cherrypy, ports

I'm using cherrypy to serve a website on two different ports.
One port is reachable from the outside, one is only used locally.
Some pages should only show up on if you use the correct port.

Currently, I'm checking `cp.request.local.port` to find out the 
current port number of a page call as in the example below.

Here on port 1700 only the index page is allowed, the `/secret` page is blocked. On port 1701 both are shown.

Is there a better way to bind of of the `RootServer2` class to a specific port?

```
import cherrypy as cp

class RootServer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Starting page
    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return '<html><body>Access from port: {}'.format(cp.request.local.port)+'</body></html>'

class RootServer2:
    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        if cp.request.local.port <> 1701:
            raise cp.HTTPError(403)
        return '<html><body>Access from port: {}'.format(cp.request.local.port) + '</body></html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cp.server.unsubscribe()  # remove the default port 8080
    cp.tree.mount(RootServer(),'',{})
    cp.tree.mount(RootServer2(),'/secret',{})
    cp._cprequest.Request.show_tracebacks = False

    server1 = cp._cpserver.Server()
    server1.socket_port = 1700
    server1._socket_host = '0.0.0.0'
    server1.thread_pool = 200
    server1.subscribe()
    server2 = cp._cpserver.Server()
    server2.socket_port = 1701
    server2._socket_host = '0.0.0.0'
    server2.thread_pool = 200
    server2.subscribe()

    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()
```

Comment: Have you tried binding one of the servers to see if it `127.0.0.1`? Also you may try screening connections via `iptables` or using some reverse proxy, e.g. `nginx`.

Comment: Also you can write a tool inside of CherryPy and do all the logic there. Apply it as a decorator on per method basis or enable for the whole class via `_cp_config`